# fancybox2 - popup doesn't shrink to fit data

Tags: jquery, fancybox

http://mayakaimal.businesscatalyst.com/media-press

Some of the popups have less data than others. I want the window to shrink to fit. i.e. in the above example if you click on "The Boston Globe" there is white space to the right.

This is my first time using fancybox. I have tried changing

```
aspectRatio: true,
didResize: true,
width: '100%'
```

Which parameter needs to be changed?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried only using a bit of text and see if it's still that wide? From my own experience Fancybox always opened up with the correct width. Is it possible that the document your showing contains css style and uses a fixed width?

Answer (score 2):

**For Fancybox 2.x**

After playing around with your code in FireBug for a while I came across the `maxWidth` option. Setting `maxWidth` to `100%` seems to fix your problem ("The Boston Globe" link now opens a Fancybox that is as skinny as the content:

```
$j("a.fancybox").fancybox({maxWidth : '100%'});
```

I also found that if you set the `fitToView` option to `false` it removes the scroll-bars and the content seems to fit in the Fancybox better:

```
$j("a.fancybox").fancybox({fitToView : false, maxWidth : '100%'});
```

**For Fancybox 1.x**

```
autoDimensions : true
```

> For inline and ajax views, resizes the view to the element recieves.
>   Make sure it has dimensions otherwise this will give unexpected
>   results

Via JavaScript you can call `$.fancybox.resize` when you change content and fancybox will resize to the proper dimensions for the content.

Comment: bbosco provided a link and he is using Fancybox v2.0.3. autoDimensions is an option for Fancybox v1.3.x and it's not a valid option for Fancybox v2.x

Comment: @JFK Thanks for the note, I answered too fast and didn't see that it was for version 2 (which I didn't know existed...). I updated my answer to something tested using Fancybox v2.

Comment: @Jasper Brilliant. Thanks. The maxWidth:100% inspired me to try maxHeight:100% and now it is all working nicely. I guess that is another way of removing the scrollbars...

Comment: Any thoughts on how to get they dynamic links to target a new window?